# Unable to insert records in database from .csv file in python2.7 (Using El Capitan )

Tags: python, mysql

I want to import data from .csv and load it in MySQL table using Python 2.7.13. I'm receiving no error however rows are not getting inserted in the table. I tried with hardcoded query and it was successfully inserted.

Code that I tried, no data inserted :

```
import csv
import MySQLdb


mydbh = MySQLdb.connect(host='**', user='**', passwd='**', db='**')
cursor = mydbh.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('load_1.csv'))

for row in csv_data:
    print row
    try:    
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `VEG_STARTERS`(`menu_cd`, `cuisene_type`, `cuisine_cd`, `cuisine_name`, `price`, `update_datetime`) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, now());", row)
        mydbh.commit()
    except:
        print "Unable to insert data"

print "%d rows were inserted" % cursor.rowcount

cursor.close()
```

Output :

> ['4\tVEG_ST\tVEG_ST_1\tROTI CHIPS\t100\t']
>   Unable to insert data
>   ['4\tVEG_ST\tVEG_ST_2\tSPICY CHEESY POPS\t140\t']
>   Unable to insert data
>   ['4\tVEG_ST\tVEG_ST_3\tMINI TACO BOMBS\t200\t']
>   Unable to insert data
>   ['4\tVEG_ST\tVEG_ST_4\tCROSTINIS\t200\t']
>   Unable to insert data
>   0 rows were inserted

Hardcoded query which worked:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb


mydbh = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root', db='restuarant')
cursor = mydbh.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO VEG_STARTERS(menu_cd, cuisene_type, cuisine_cd, cuisine_name, price, update_datetime) VALUES ( 4, 'VEG_ST', 'VEG_ST_6', 'TEST', 100.15, now())")
mydbh.commit()

print "%d rows were inserted" % cursor.rowcount

cursor.close()
```

I searched online but I was unable to find solution which will solve my problem. Any suggestion are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are tab seperated (`\t`). Try:

```
csv_data = csv.reader(file('load_1.csv'), delimiter='\t')
```

when reading the csv-file.

Comment: @Toterich..I tried that after reading your post, still not working.

Comment: Did the output change at all? As a general suggestion, you can replace your `except`-statement with `except Exception as e: print(e)` to get get information on what exactly went wrong.